# HTML Head with scripts for different regional languages?

Tags: html, cookies, head, regional-settings

I am working with a ready script for cookie policy in Europe.
The problem, my CMS by Hubspot only allows globally headers for all content or individual heads for each page. With our 120 pages it is hard to define it manually, but we need a script for the German pages and a script for the Frend pages.

Here the scripts:

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#1d89d2"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#fff",
      "text": "#333"
    }
  },
  "position": "top",
  "static": true,
  "content": {
    "message": "SORBA verwendet Cookies, um Ihr Online-Erlebnis zu verbessern. Mit der weiteren Nutzung von sorba.ch akzeptieren Sie unsere:
",
    "dismiss": "Schliessen",
    "link": "Datenschutzerklärung",
    "href": "www.sorba.ch/datenschutz"
  }
})});
</script>


<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#1d89d2"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#fff",
      "text": "#333"
    }
  },
  "position": "top",
  "static": true,
  "content": {
    "message": "SORBA utilise des cookies pour améliorer votre expérience de navigation. Si vous poursuivez l’utilisation de sorba.ch, vous acceptez notre :
",
    "dismiss": "Fermer",
    "link": "Politique de confidentialité",
    "href": "www.sorba.ch/fr-ch/politique_confidentialite"
  }
})});
</script>
```

Is there any possibility to identify the content language of the page and to activate just one script?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current page language from `<html lang="en">` tag.

```
var current_lang = $('html').attr('lang');
if(current_lang == 'de'){
   //show Deutsch messge
} else if(current_lang == 'en'){
   //show English message
}
```